# Entity Framework Connection error event

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to catch all SQLExceptions (connection error, timeout, etc) that EF might throw in a single place. I'm using a unit of work pattern with DI so there's no `var using = context` for example. Calls like `.Single` or `.ToList` are used all around the business logic.

Is there any hook or event of class I could overwrite or inject to do this?

Comment: This link might help you ://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221951/sqlexception

Comment: Why do you want to catch all these exceptions in one place? You should investigate what's going on. Or do you want to log those exceptions?

Comment: Should have mentioned that we have two DbContext connecting to two different databases. I want to catch these specific exceptions because we have monitoring that I need to tell there was a Database connection error. So a global handler on application leven isn't gonna work since there won't be a way for me to tell to which db I was querying.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Unit of Work eventually calls `DbContext.SaveChanges()`, you can wrap this call with a try-catch.

Another option, which requires some discipline from your development team, is to add two methods in a base BL class: `IList<T> MaterializeList<T>(IQueriable<T> query)` and `T MaterializeSingle<T>(IQueriable<t> query)`, which will look something like this:

```
protected IList<T> MaterializeList<T>(IQueriable<T> query) {
    try {
        return query.ToList();
    }
    catch {
        //your error handling code here
    }
}
```

and

```
protected T MaterializeSingle<T>(IQueriable<t> query) {
    try {
        return query.FirstOrDefault();
    }
    catch {
        //your error handling code here
    }
}
```

and then always materialize using these methods.

As a side note, I try to keep my LINQ to Entities queries in my Data Access layer, leaving the Business Logic layer ignorant of the data access technology.

Comment: That's not gonna work. I'm not getting to SaveChanges when I can't connect to my database

Comment: @E.Staal,  Depending on the type of your application, you can use a global exception handler, that will catch all errors, including your EF errors. In an ASP.NET MVC, you can define a global custom error handler inheriting from `HandleErrorAttribute`, which will catch your EF errors from all of your application. That's how I did it in a recent project.

Comment: Should have mentioned that we have two DbContext connecting to two different databases. I want to catch these specific exceptions because we have monitoring that I need to tell there was a Database connection error. So a global handler on application leven isn't gonna work since there won't be a way for me to tell to which db I was querying.

Comment: I'm now writing extensionmethods (wrappers) aound EF's QueryableExtensions and kinda doing what you are describing above.

Answer (score 0):

Little bit work to do, but this will help you i think:

Encapsulate you `DbContext` withing a fake-context and hide your `DbSets`. You build an new context which will be the context for you business-logic. This one doesn't give access to the `DbSets`, it shows custom-dbSets to the user. The main work will be to build the fake-context, which needs to have all methods you're using on the real dbSets.

```
/// <summary>
/// This sould no be used anywhere except in MyDbContext2
/// </summary>
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<SomeTableClass> SomeTable { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// This will be your context in the business-logic
/// </summary>
public class MyDbContext2
{
    private MyDbContext realDb;

    public MyDbContext2(string conStr)
    {
        realDb = new MyDbContext();
    }

    public MyDbSet<SomeTableClass> SomeFakeTable { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Fake-set with logging
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
public class MyDbSet<T> where T : class
{
    private DbSet<T> dbSet;

    public MyDbSet(DbSet<T> realDbSet)
    {
        this.dbSet = realDbSet;
    }

    public List<T> ToList()
    {
        try
        {
            return dbSet.ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Do some logging..
            throw;
        }
    }

    public T SingleOrDefault()
    {
        try
        {
            return dbSet.SingleOrDefault();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Do some logging..
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

A good idea would be to rename you `DbContext` and introduce a the fake-one with the old name. This way Visual Studio will show you which methods you have to implement.